# portaudio.h: No such file or directory on Windows 10

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, pyaudio

I'm trying to install pyaudio on Windows 10.  I'm getting this error:

```
src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
```

Comment: `portaudio.h` means C/C++ code which it has to compile and it may need to install C/C++ source code of `portaudio` or at least C/C++ headers. On Linux Mint ? Ubuntu it means to install `portaudio-dev` using `apt-get`, not `pip`. But on Windows it can make problem.

Comment: there is [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and there is precompiled `pyaudio` - maybe it will works.

Comment: I went to the Unofficial Windows Binaries....Tried to install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win32, thinking that would be for my Python version 3.7.4, but got message "not a supported wheel on this platform".

Comment: do you use 32bit Python? If you have 64bit Python then you need `win_amd64`

Comment: Thanks so much for your clarification!  That did the trick!  I'm good to go!